# Does $\frac{1}{\ln^2(x)}$ or $\displaystyle\sum_\limits{p \leq \sqrt{\frac{x}{2}}}\frac{1}{(p\ln(\frac{x}{p^2}))^2}$ grow faster.

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, derivatives, prime-numbers

I'm currently doing some self-research relating to some series of prime numbers, and I got to the question of whether
$$\frac{1}{\ln^2(x)}$$ or $$\sum_{p \leq \sqrt{\frac{x}{2}}}\frac{1}{(p\ln(\frac{x}{p^2}))^2}$$ grows faster, where $p$ means prime numbers. (It's best if they grow the same rate/they are asymptotically similar... something like that haha).

Currently attempted to use things like the Lamber W function and simple derivatives but I'm not like a professional in number theory or analysis so maybe if there are some tips or any equations/theorems I can be acknowledged of so that I can approach this.

Comment: I think $1/\ln^2 x$ does not grow...

Comment: the second sum has lots of terms ($\approx \sqrt x /\log x$) so is quite big

Comment: @Conrad Hi, do you mind if you can please explain why it is approximately equal to $\sqrt{x}/\log{x}$? Thank you very much.

Comment: @Conrad Hi again, sorry, the question was written slightly wrong... Do you mind helping me with the revised one? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

We use the prime number theorem in the form, there exists $c>0$ st: $$\pi(y)=\text{li} (y)+O(ye^{-c\sqrt {\ln y}})$$ so $d\pi(y)=\frac{dy}{\ln y}+d(O(ye^{-c\sqrt {\ln y}}))$. Then:

$$S(x)=\sum_{p \leq \sqrt{\frac{x}{2}}}\frac{1}{(p\ln(\frac{x}{p^2}))^2}=\int_2^{\sqrt{\frac{x}{2}}}\frac{d\pi(y)}{(y\ln(\frac{x}{y^2}))^2}=\int_2^{\sqrt{\frac{x}{2}}}\frac{d(y)}{(y\ln(\frac{x}{y^2}))^2\ln y}+E(x)$$
where $$E(x)=\int_2^{\sqrt{\frac{x}{2}}}\frac{d(O(ye^{-c\sqrt {\ln y}}))}{(y\ln(\frac{x}{y^2}))^2}=O(\frac{1}{\ln^2 x})+o(x^{-1/2})+O(\int_2^{\sqrt{\frac{x}{2}}}\frac{e^{-c\sqrt {\ln y}}dy}{y^3\ln(\frac{x}{y^2})^2})$$ integrating by parts since $\frac{d}{dy}\frac{1}{(y\ln(\frac{x}{y^2}))^2}=O(\frac{1}{y^3\ln(\frac{x}{y^2})^2)}$ by a simple computation when $y^2 \le x/2$ so $\ln(\frac{x}{y^2}) >>1$

Hence majorizing trivially $e^{-c\sqrt {\ln y}} << 1$ we get that $$\int_2^{\sqrt{\frac{x}{2}}}\frac{dy}{y^3\ln(\frac{x}{y^2})^2}=\int_2^{x^{1/3}}\frac{dy}{y^3\ln(\frac{x}{y^2})^2}+\int_{x^{1/3}}^{\sqrt{\frac{x}{2}}}\frac{dy}{y^3\ln(\frac{x}{y^2})^2}$$ and using $\ln(\frac{x}{y^2}) \ge \frac{\ln x}{3}$ in the first integral and $\ln(\frac{x}{y^2}) \ge \ln 2$ in the second we get that  $E(x)=O(\frac{1}{\ln^2 x})$

Similarly for the main term $$\int_2^{\sqrt{\frac{x}{2}}}\frac{d(y)}{(y\ln(\frac{x}{y^2}))^2\ln y}$$ we use $\ln y \ge \ln 2$ and split the integral as above in two parts and use the same majorizations for $\ln(\frac{x}{y^2})$ to get it $O(\frac{1}{\ln^2 x})$ too.

$S(x) \ge \frac{1}{(2\ln(\frac{x}{4}))^2}$ so the sum has magnitude $C\frac{1}{\ln^2 x}$ though trying to do an asymptotic by integrating by parts repeatedly, while possible, seems quite messy.

Comment: Thanks... as a high schooler this would take me a few months to understand but I really appreciate your help haha.

Comment: Happy to be of help - most anything dealing with sums indexed by prime numbers requires the prime number theorem with a good reminder and summation and integration by parts, so would focus understanding those first

Comment: Thanks... One more question, base don what you wrote above, would $\lim_{x\to\infty} (\frac{1}{\ln^2(x)} - \sum_{p \leq \sqrt{\frac{x}{2}}}\frac{1}{(p\ln(\frac{x}{p^2}))^2})$ be equal to $0$ then?

Comment: mot necessarily - what we can say is that $A\frac{1}{\ln^2(x)} \le S(x) \le B\frac{1}{\ln^2(x)}$ but we need to investigate $A,B$ closer to deduce something like the above; similarly there is a possibility that there is an asymptotic $\frac{1}{\ln^2(x)}=C S(x)+E(x)$ with $E(x)=o(\frac{1}{\ln^2(x)})$ but again that would requirer a finer analysis and it gets messy quickly

Comment: Hi, first of all thank you very much for the help. If it doesn't bother you, do you mind if I can have any sort of contact (insta, gmail etc) so that I can ask you questions for help regarding this/other math Qs? It would be very appreciated if it is possible but of course you don't need to if you feel uncomfortable about it.

Comment: Hi, I have been looking at this for a while (though I still don't really get it). Do you mind if you can help me with this approach? (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4848189/1238984)

Comment: By the way, the statement I am trying to prove is $$\frac{x}{(\ln(x))^2} - \sum_{p \leq \frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{2}}}\frac{\frac{x}{p^2}}{(\ln(\frac{x}{p^2}))^2} = O(\sqrt{x}\ln(x))$$

Comment: why do you think that is true?

Comment: Oh this is actually something related to the Riemann hypothesis... Im just assuming that it is true.

Comment: I can maybe give you some more information about the research I did until now to get to this conclusion but when I wake up tomorrow in Korean time cuz its 1am right now haha

Comment: put it in the post where you ask - motivation etc - partial summation may work at least to show the difference is $o(x/log^2 x)$ since the bulk of the sum is concentrated at small primes and when $p \approx x^a$ then the corresponding part of the sum say from $p^a$ to $2p^a$ is $\approx (\frac{x}{(\ln(x))^2})O(x^{-a})=O(\frac{x}{(\ln(x))^2})o(1)$ so dyadic decomposition may work to show the $o(x/log^2 x)$

Comment: Hi, before I do so, may I ask, if $f(x) \sim g(x)$, then if I do any calculations regarding $\lim_{x\to\infty} g(x)$, can I just substitute $g(x)$ with $f(x)$ and calculate it? For example, if $f(x) \sim 2x^2+2x+1$ then if I am calculating $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{f(x)}{3x^2+1}$ then can I substitute it to get $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{2x^2+2x+1}{3x^2+1}$ can get $\frac{2}{3}$? If this makes sense...

Comment: Depends what you mean of $\sim$ and what computations you do; if $f\sim g$ means $f/g \to 1$ you definitely can deduce from $g/h \to 5$ that $f/h \to 5$ but for more complicated stuff you may have to take into account the error $f/g-1$

Comment: By $f \sim g$ I mean $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 1$

Comment: All depends on the computations you do - usually the best thing to do is to explicit everything with limits and epsilon and delta until you get the confidence you are doing it right - especially if you deal with difficult and subtle things

Comment: Sort of hard to understand right now... I'll edit my post to add motivations/work until now it might take a bit but do you mind if you can check my progress? Of course I don't expect myself to "prove" this but im trying to write a research paper on the hypothesis! (though im a high schooler haha)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150997/discussion-between-ncy-and-conrad).